# Problem regarding inequality

Tags: inequality

If $a,b,c,d$ are non-negative real numbers and $a+b+c+d=1$, the maximum value of $ab+bc+cd=\frac{p}{q}$ then value of $p+q$ will be _____ ?

**My Approach**:-

I've tried both AM-GM inequality and Cauchy-Schwarz inequalities on $a,b,c,d$ with no result. Is there any elegant way to do this without computing $(a+b+c+d)^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$f(a,b,c,d) = ab+bc+cd, g(a,b,c,d)=a+b+c+d-1,
\nabla(f) = \lambda\nabla(g)\Rightarrow (b,a+c,b+d,c)=\lambda(1,1,1,1)\Rightarrow b=a+c=b+d=c\Rightarrow a=d=0,b=c=\dfrac{1}{2}\Rightarrow f_{\max}= bc=b^2 = \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \dfrac{1}{4}\Rightarrow p = 1,q= 4\Rightarrow p+q=5$$

Comment: Could you please explain what you have done?

Comment: What does the inverted triangle mean?

Comment: Its the gradient of a function $\nabla(f) = (f_a,f_b,f_c,f_d)$

Comment: why does $\nabla f = \lambda\nabla g$

Comment: Ok... I just googled Legrange Multipliers.... Thanks a lot. Nice solve